Veins 5.2 not works using sumo-gui command instead of veins_launchd scrippt: Answered with error to command 0x03: Wrong position in requestMessage
I'm working with veins. I have to use multiple connection on sumo, so I changed the scenario.ned file in order to use TraCiScenarioManager instead of TraCiScenarioManagerLaunchd, like this:
manager: TraCIScenarioManager{
        parameters:
            @display("p=512,128");
    }

Then I launch the sumo-gui script:
sumo-gui -c <path_to_my_sumocfg> --remote-port 9999

and in the end launch the omnet++ simulation. When I press the play button I see the client connect to the sumo server, but after hit the play button onto the sumo-gui, an error appear:
Error: Answered with error to command 0x03: Wrong position in requestMessage after dispatching command 3. Expected command length was 12 but 6 Bytes were read.
Can you help me? Thanks.
I'm using Omnet++ 6.0.3;
veins 5.2;
Sumo 1.8.0.
Thank you
